# Is it possible to keyframe-css animate a div counter-clockwise over pi?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

### **Question:**

**Is it possible to animate the inner-circle `.watch-face` from 12 o'clock, counter clockwise, a full rotation or 2πr in only css keyframes?**

---

Here would be the look of the completed animation:
[image]

### **COMPLETED ANIMATION:**

[image: completed animation]

### Check out Live code starting point: [Code sample](http://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/MybgJp)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="watch-container">
  <div class="watch-face"></div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
$watch-face-size: 165;
$watch-border-size: 185;

.watch-face {
  height: $watch-face-size + px;
  width: $watch-face-size + px;
  background: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: $watch-face-size + px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

  &.animate-counter-clockwise {
    //How to write a keyframe animation to animate from
  }


  &::after {
    content: "10";
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 68px;
    color: #fff;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: -3px;

  }

  &::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    border: 5px solid green;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: $watch-border-size + px;
    width: $watch-border-size + px;
    height: $watch-border-size + px;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
  }
}

//boilerplate styles
html {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
    -ms-box-sizing: inherit;
    -o-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

.watch-container {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use SVG for this animation, see [the solution codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGyEoz?editors=1100):

```
<div class="watch-container">
  <div class="watch-face">
    <svg class="animator">
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="100" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

So you can animate the circle with simple:

```
@-webkit-keyframes clock-animation {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
  33% { stroke-dashoffset: 628; }
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 628; }
}

.animator {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  circle {
    animation: clock-animation 3s linear infinite;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-dasharray: 628;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-width: 200px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  }
}
```

Short description: you need to create an SVG with a circle element inside. The circle element has a border (stroke) which in fact fills the whole circle size. Then you need to define the stroke appearance with `stroke-dasharray` which sets up the width of one stroke dash (100% in our case) and manipulate this single big dash with `stroke-dashoffset`. The offset moves the dash and it slightly goes away out of the circle.

I picked the numbers manually with simple guessing / chrome console, but they are quite calculatable with normal school geometry rules, and SASS helps here a lot.

What's really comfortable with this method is you need only one SVG element and a really small piece of CSS. It looks very pretty and makes you remember the school days, that's why this is my favorite way of doing these things.

Inspired by [this awesome progress bar implementation](http://codepen.io/JMChristensen/pen/Ablch)

Comment: Upvoted and for the record used your answer.  But My question was to do it in css so I feel obligated to give the cred to cameron little.  Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you'd animate with your current markup. As far as I know, animating a div radially like that isn't possible. However, you can fake it by rotating squares and adding some covering. Here's a demo:

http://codepen.io/apexskier/pen/wGovRy

```html
<div class="watch-face animating">
  <div class="cover"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
</div>
```

`a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` represent the four quadrants of your clock, each will be rotated about the middle and shown and hidden as appropriate. `cover` is used to hide the first one as it's gradually shown.

I used `z-index` to properly layer things.

Here's some of the important css (see the codepen for everything)

EDIT: Fixed borders around quadrant by making the whole thing an even width

```css
.watch-face {
  .a, .b, .c, .d, .cover {
    position: absolute;
height: ($watch-face-size / 2);
width: ($watch-face-size / 2);
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 5;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    border-top-left-radius: ($watch-face-size / 2) - 1;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff; // hides a nasty green aliasing line
    border-left: 1px solid #fff; // hides a nasty green aliasing line
  }
  .cover {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  &.animating, &.animate {
    .a, .b, .c, .d, .cover {
      animation-duration: 4s;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
  }

  &.animating {
    .a, .b, .c, .d, .cover {
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
  }

  &.animate {
    .a, .b, .c, .d, .cover {
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
    }
  }

  .a {
    animation-name: clock-a;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  .b {
    animation-name: clock-b;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  .c {
    animation-name: clock-c;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
  .d {
    animation-name: clock-d;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  .cover {
    animation-name: clock-cover;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}

@keyframes clock-cover {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  74.9999999% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes clock-a {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

@keyframes clock-b {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  24.999999% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes clock-c {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  49.999999% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes clock-d {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  74.999999% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```